# tpm_tis Operation Timed out when booting 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, tpm

Since upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 (with `do-release-upgrade`) my computer (Sony vgn-sz1vp) hangs for 4 minutes when booting.

```
[    1.015598] tpm_tis 00:06: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xB, rev-id 16)
[    1.019920] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
[    1.321725] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[   93.668058] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[  121.040029] tpm_tis 00:06: Operation Timed out
[  121.052385] tpm_tis 00:06: A TPM error (-62) occurred attempting to determine the timeouts
[  241.088029] tpm_tis 00:06: Operation Timed out
[  241.100484] tpm_tis 00:06: Could not get TPM timeouts and durations
```

So far I have tried:

- enabling and disabling TPM in the BIOS (no change)
- adding blacklist items for tpm_tis (and other TPM modules) in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf (no change)

Is there a boot parameter I can add to grub to tell the kernel to stop trying to communicate with the TPM hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press '`e`' at boot menu. Add the command `nolapic` after `ro` in the boot options. You can add this to grub file:

Edit your `grub.cfg` and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nolapic"
```

Save file, then run `update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the following lines in my `/etc/default/grub` file has solved the problem:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=nomsi quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="tpm_tis.interrupts=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

tpm is compiled into the stock Ubuntu kernel, so there is no way to disable it completely with a boot parameter or by blacklisting.

To resolve this issue on a Vaio SZ3 with Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu), I had rebuild the kernel with tpm disabled, as follows:

Follow [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) for the basic process, with the following additions:

- Run the menuconfig step as described in 'Modifying the configuration'. Select Y to edit the 'i386 generic' or 'amd64 generic' configuration (N to all others). Once in menuconfig, use the / command to search for CONFIG_IMA, press 1 (or whichever number is indicated) to navigate to it, and N to disable it. Do the same for CONFIG_TPM. I also disabled CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO to reduce the disk space required for the build.
- Before building, `touch debian.master/abi/i386/ignore` (or amd64) to disable the ABI checks, which would fail due to missing TPM and changed hashes (if you disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO like me).
- Before installing the .debs that are built, you may need to `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-$(uname -r) linux-tools-common`

Bear in mind that you'll need to prevent the kernel being automatically updated in future, or go through this process again with the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same thing and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1308264) fix worked like a charm

```
# edit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash tpm_tis.force=1"
```