# Desktop 14.04 stuck during installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, tpm

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Both from USB and CD, it gets stuck at this screen. It briefly responds to keyboard input before not responding at all.

I've run it selecting acpi=off and nomodeset with the same results.

I'm using a HP Compaq Elite 8100.

Comment: Possibly [bug #1427860](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1427860)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution was to install 12.04 using acpi=off and nomodeset, then updating to 14.04 via Software Updater.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant error here is:

```
"A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value"
```

There seems to be an incompatibility with a TPM (trusted platform module) security chip your machine has. Try to look through the BIOS for an option to disable it. If you google around for this error, you will also find people working around this problem by *enabling* the chip when it was disabled before.

If that doesn't help, have a look at [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486329/tpm-tis-operation-timed-out-when-booting-14-04-lts). It seems the boot just hangs for a couple of minutes. So you could still boot and install and fix the problem as described in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wasn't able to find TPM settings in the BIOS though.

Comment: @Anastasia, what about the second part of my answer?

Comment: I took a quick look at it and it seemed like it applies to an already installed Ubuntu and involved modifying some files as well... I wasn't too confident with that as I'm a newbie to Linux, so I didn't try it.

My boot also hung for a longer time, about 10-15 minutes before I powered off my PC.