# Random striped lines on my screen (Intel 82Q35 GPU)

Tags: intel-graphics, screen-corruption

I have white or black horizontal striped lines on my windows.

lspci :

```
root@ubuntu15:~# lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2636
```

How to fix it ?

Thank you.

Here comes screenshots.

[Crappy lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWgp7.png)

[What the hell are these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMxwX.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [bug #1393205 - 
Intel q35 bug on Ubuntu 14.04 (Screen Artifacts)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1393205) which is fixed by upgrading to a later kernel (3.19 or later). Make sure you have latest drivers installed as well (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`).

Comment: you right, i have the same bug.  uname -a gives this :

`Linux ubuntu15 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:32:18 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

It's the latest kernel

Comment: Try installing the latest [drm-nightly](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-nightly/) kernel and [xserver-xorg-video-intel from xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) - and if it still occurs [ask the Intel developers on the upstream bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45092).

Comment: I installed the last drm 4.4.0-994 but it doesn't boot. And my xserver-xorg-video-intel is also the last.

Comment: What was the error? Perhaps you can try [mainline 4.4](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/)? Though 4.2 is pretty recent anyway.. [Report a new bug on freedesktop.org](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs) and mention that it's the same as bug #45092 (you should be able to add a link in the "see also" field). Since 3.19 is specifically mentioned as being fixed, you might also want to give that a try, there could be a regression.

Comment: It looks like the fix only works for gen4 chipsets but your q35 is gen3. It's a long shot but try [this patch](http://pastebin.com/c41wEwWv).

Comment: Here is the error : `tpm_tls 00:09: A TPM error(7) occured attempting to read a pcr value`

Instead, I can boot with failsafe mode. And there is no striped line anymore. But the resolution can't be up to 1024.

Gotta try the patch. Thanks.

Comment: [TPM question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597226/desktop-14-04-stuck-during-installation). Possibly it isnt' the TPM hanging, it's the nvidia driver loading after the TPM driver. Failsafe would account for that. One of the answers suggests that after waiting for a few minutes the boot will resume.

Comment: Hi again. Finaly, it's OK.

I installed the `4.4.0-040400-generic` as you suggested.

I stucked on this problem for many months. Now everything is OK. Thank you very much !!!